# Separate frontend application - build and deployment strategies

Tags: java, javascript, frontend, gruntjs

There is an opinion that when building rich browser applications (JS-heavy) it should be treated as separate application not as a part of the "backend" app. I wonder how is build and deployment realized in such setup?

Say I have java WAR file which exposes JSON-based API (be it JAX-RS or whatever) - no views. Then I have static content for my frontend app: js script html views, css styles, images etc. I could use dedicated build tool e.g. GruntJS for that project to minify/preprocess etc.

But now I'm kind of stuck. What should be result of such build? Separate WAR with only static files created by Grunt? What about the deployment? Should I mix those WARs together into one full-blown app or deploy two separate e.g. `example.com` serves static and those statics use `api.example.com` to get data.

Another question is about development. As a result I'd like to have my js and css concatenated and minified, but it's not so good for development (debugging is hard etc.). Is there any trick to have separate source files in dev mode and concatenated only on prod build?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dabbled in Java WebDev in like forever, so I won't be able to help you with specifics. But the idea behind such abstractions is usually to expose a public backend API, and thus be able to connect to the backend with any type of client written in any language residing on any host. If you happen to develop the API and the Client, your question should be if there ever is a chance that client and API need to be deployed separately. If there is, build them separately. If not, don't. Personally, I would favor your api.example.com and example.com scenario.

Regarding your second topic: 
I once build an ANT script to do exactly that. Have your JS "Classes" in separate "namespaced" files and let the script concatenate and minify them. You had to enter the files in the correct order into the build script, which is easily managed in small projects. Idk if there are automated tools for that by now.